# Помогите с программой для заметок

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите сделать так чтобы при редактировании файла на экран выводилось его содержимое и можно было его стереть(не очистить весь файл)

````
mas = []
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    mas.append(str(filename))
def sozd():
    try:
        x=input('название файла:')
    except:
        print('такого файла не существует')
        x=input('название файла:')
    f = open(x, 'w')
    inf()
def red():
    try:
        x=input('название файла:')
    except:
        print('такого файла не существует')
        x=input('название файла:')
    f = open(x)
    fd=f.read()
    print(fd)
def izm():
    try:
        x=input('название файла:')
    except:
        print('такого файла не существует')
        x=input('название файла:')
    f=open(x, 'r+')
    fd=f.read()
    y=str(input(fd))
    f.write(y)
def inf():
    i=0
    print('все файлы:')
    for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
        print(mas[i])
        i+=1
print('1-создание файла,  2-чтение,  3-редактировать, 4-выход')
inf()
u=input('выбери действие:')
while u != '4':
    if u=='1':
        sozd()
        u=input('выбери действие:')
    if u=='2':
        red()
        u=input('выбери действие:')
    if u=='3':
        izm()
        u=input('выбери действие:')
    if u=='4':
        break
    else:
        print('1-создание файла,  2-чтение,  3-редактировать')
        u=input('выбери действие:')
        if u=='1':
            sozd()
            u=input('выбери действие:')
        if u=='2':
            red()
            u=input('выбери действие:')         
        if u=='3':
            izm()
            u=input('выбери действие:')```
````

Comment: Вам стоит начать с задач попроще. Например, сделать осмысленными блоки try...except.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Общие советы**

Коду требуется полноценный рефакторинг. Не за чем использовать несколько одинаковых конструкций в цикле. Также почитай про with statement. Вопрос на stackoverflow, чтобы его нашли и проиндексировали, нужно задавать описанием конкретной проблемы, а не просьбой помощи. Код для примера лучше брать лаконичный с тем куском, который вызывает трудности. Целиком разбирать или дописывать программу будут не многие.

#### **Ответ на вопрос: Как редактировать stdout?**

Ты можешь использовать динамический вывод с помощью метода [getch()](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) и цикла

Пример:
https://asciinema.org/a/238478

**Код:**

```
# Script make you able to edit printed text
# stdin and stdout at the same time
# https://asciinema.org/a/238478
# https://gist.github.com/SoleSensei/05a97bbe8b75cd2368a8e6d5e00d6047
import sys
from getch import getch

def flush_append(char):
    # just append char to the end
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()

def flush_write(line):
    # clear all and rewrite line
    sys.stdout.write(f"\r{' '*100}\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()

def interactive_input(line):
    flush_write(line)
    c = getch()
    while ord(c) not in (13, 3): # 13 - Enter, 3 - Ctrl+C
        if ord(c) in (127, 8): # 127,8 - Backspace (Unix, Windows)
            line = line[:-1]
            flush_write(line)
        else:
            # decode to string if byte
            c = c.decode('ascii') if str(c)[0] == 'b' else c
            line += c
            flush_append(c)
        c = getch()
    print() # add EOL
    return line


s = interactive_input('stdout editable line')
```